# How do I set the value of a variable to the user input in an input field?

Tags: javascript, input

I am creating a random password generator and I would like the user to be able to set the desired length of their password. I have an input field for the user to put their desired length, and I would like to store their input in a variable. I have tried several stack overflow solutions, none of which have worked.

Here is what I have right now for the HTML:

```
<div id = "pswrdLngth">
            <div class = "text-center">
                <p>Desired password length:</p>
                <input type="text" id = "lengthValue" name="userInput" size="25" placeholder="Enter a # between 8-128">
            </div>   
    </div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var lengthValue = document.querySelector("#lengthValue"); 
var passwordLength = lengthValue.value;

$(".buttonTwo").on("click", function() {
    console.log(passwordLength); 
} )
```

The console is returning an empty line when buttonTwo is clicked. I have also tried using "lengthValue.val()" for the function passwordLength, but the console error read: ".val() is not a function." Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why is passwordLength not a variable?

Comment: oops, it is, i just copy and pasted incorrectly. will edit now - disregard that.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myFunction = () => {
  var lengthValue = document.querySelector("#lengthValue");
  var passwordLength = lengthValue.value;
  console.log(passwordLength)
}
```

html:

```
<div id = "pswrdLngth">
            <div class = "text-center">
                <p>Desired password length:</p>
                <input type="text" id = "lengthValue" name="userInput" size="25" placeholder="Enter a # between 8-128" onchange="myFunction()">
            </div>   
    </div>
```

I made an onchange function which will store the value everytime the input changes.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. I tried this and got the error: 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLmyFunction.onchange (index.html:77)
onchange @ index.html:77"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Event Listener like this:

```
var lengthValue = document.getElementById("lengthValue"); 
var passwordLength = lengthValue.value;
document.getElementById('buttonTwo').addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(passwordLength); 
} )
```

This should work if the HTML for buttonTwo has an id called "buttonTwo", like this:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonTwo">
```